# If I edit a design from PDF in Acrobat Pro DC, is it print ready without further steps?

Tags: print-design, cmyk, adobe-acrobat

The original PDF (which I want to edit) has previously been sent to a printing company with successful results. The PDF was sent in CMYK color mode so colors post print were as expected. If I edit this PDF in Acrobat Pro DC, do the color values remain the same as te original? Is tere any reason wy it would not be ready to print or print to te same quality post edit?

Comment: *Really* depends on what and how you edit anything. This, as it stands, is unanswerable.

Comment: At present I only want to delete a text box and send this for the next round of printing. I am still learning to use Acrobat- if it's possible to add to the original design whilst keeping the color and print quality consistent, I would like to do this too

Answer (score 1):

If you only delete things you should usually be fine. If you add text or objects you can select the color in the edit tools. When you click on the color patch there you are able to define the color space and should use CMYK for your purpose.

If you have Acrobat DC it is also always a good idea to check PDFs using the Preflight tool, e.g in "Prepress, Color and Transparency" in the group "Prepress" the Profile "Sheetfed offset (CMYK) (GWG 2015)".

You might see some unexpected errors but you would also see if you have color definitions that are unlikely to print well like DeviceRGB or so.